# create a binding from a DataListView to a list consisting of a list

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to create a two way binding from a DataListView to a list consisting of a list. How do I do that?

Based on the code below, I create a list like this:

```
   probe1 probe2 probe3 probe4 ...
1  12.3   4.2    6.3    12.5 
2  65.2   2.5    12.4   54.6 
3  54.2   64.3   21.5   22.2 
. . .
```

- Row header is the row in Values. <372 values
- Column header is row in Probes. <120 probes
- Totalt max 44640 values but usually a few thousand values

And the code

```
public IList<Probe> Probes{get;private set;}

public class Probe
{
   public Probe(int maxValues)
   {
      Values = new double[maxValues];
   }
   public IList<double> Values{get;private set}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to flatten the list first. Create a new type like ProbeValue containing both the property Value:double and Probe:Probe. Then create a new CollectionView from the flattened result and apply a GroupDescription on the Probe property. Bind your listview against that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx

Comment: CollectionView is a class from PresentationFramework.dll, but my application is a WinForms-application. So I can't use it.

Comment: Your right, sorry for that. Have you red this? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListView_DataBinding.aspx

It will be hard to do this out of the box. You can either overwrite from the listView and next to the databinding logic above, also dynamicly create columns although this will be alot of work. Another dirty hack is to provide a flattened list where each entry has X probes as properies where only one is specified.